# Parsing through a file using perl and string concatenation

Tags: perl

*I'm trying to parse through the file and collecting  types of mismatches in the different modules and generating an xls.     Below is the report pattern i need to parse( but actual report pattern is not simple as below):*

```
outsocket ports in design1 not in design2
a 
b
Insocket ports in design1 not in design2
g
h
```

There can be many design name(pushed to module list using `$module`) in the log but this pattern will not change.(Insocket/outsocket/othertype  ports in `<>` not in `<>`)

Below is my core code.I'm facing issue with this code and it is not working(especially string concatenation) as expected please help me fix this.

```
while ($line = <FH>)  {
  if ( $line =~ /Insocket(\s*)ports(\s*)in(\s*)${design1}(\s*)not(\s*)in(\s*)${design2}/) { 
         $mismatch_type = "type_i_n";
    } 
 elsif ($line =~ /Insocket(\s*)ports(\s*)in(\s*)${design2}(\s*)not(\s*)in(\s*)${design1}/)    {
        $mismatch_type = "type_i_r";
    } 

elsif ( $line =~ /outsocket(\s*)ports(\s*)in(\s*)${design2}(\s*)not(\s*)in(\s*)${design1}/ ) { 
        $mismatch_type = "type_o_n";
    } 

elsif ( $line =~ /outsocket(\s*)ports(\s*)in(\s*)${design1}(\s*)not(\s*)in(\s*)${design2}/ ) {
        $mismatch_type = "type_o_r";
    }

         $result = $mismatch_type . "_code_ " . $module; 
         $$result = $$result .$line;  
         if(!present_in_list ($module,@module_list)) {
             push @module_list,$module;
         }
         push @mismatch_type_list,$mismatch_type;
}#PARSING OF FILE ENDS


#NOW PROCESSING THE RESULTS BASED ON PARSING
foreach $module (@module_list) {
        foreach $each_mismatch (@mismatch_type_list) {
            $result = $mismatch_type . "_code_ " . $module;
            print FH2" $$result,";
                                                                                                   }
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the code is not working? What are the results of the program, and how did you expect it to work differently? Since this is an incomplete program and we have only a very loose idea of what kind of data you're working on, it's hard to guess what you might need.

Comment: You really should use proper indentation. It will help your programming a great deal.

Comment: Im trying to associate each of the mismatch type($mismatch_type) to a module($module) during parsing and finally taking each module from my list and displaying the associated line ($line) which were concatenated during parsing

Comment: during parsing i need to associate each of the mismatch type to the module and in this way finally i have a collection of modules and collection of mismatch associated with each module. So that i can display them to a file using for each loop

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of guesses and general suggestions. I'm not sure this will fix your problem, but it will probably help:

1. The first two regexes have an extra `}` in `${design1}}` and `${design2}}`. Not sure if this is present in your original program or if it's an error that was introduced in posting here.
2. It looks like you're using string concatenation to build up the name of a `$result` variable, so you can then use that string as the name of *another* variable like `$type_i_n_code_module_a`. I strongly recommend that to reduce confusion, that you use a hash instead:

   ```
   %result = ();
   while ($line = <FH>) {
       ...
       $result_key = $mismatch_type . "_code_ " . $module;
       $result{$result_key} = $result{$result_key} . $line;
   }

   ...
   foreach $module (@module_list) {
       foreach $each_mismatch (@mismatch_type_list) {
           $result_key = $mismatch_type . "_code_ " . $module;
           print FH2" $result{$result_key},";
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: extra } is because of typo. can u please let me know why my code is not working and provide me some details on your explanation of hash.

Comment: I don't know why your code is not working, because you haven't said what it's actually doing and you haven't shown us the input that causes it to behave that way. So all I can do is guess. As for the hash: a hash is a variable also called an "associative array" or "dictionary" in other languages. It maps arbitrary keys to values, so if your hash variable is `%result` then you can have `$result{'type_i_n_code_module'} = 'abcde'` and `$result{'type_o_r_code_module'} = 'fghij'` and so on. It is a cleaner solution to saving different parts of your file in different variables.

Comment: The [`perldata` man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) is a good place to read up on hashes and how to use them, if you are not familiar with these data structures.

Comment: I have seen  $$result = $$result .$line; this type of parsing in other perl codes..wondering why it is not working for me.thanks any way